# stop $resource from encoding URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, osrm

Working on a a routing system using OSRM.  Right now I'm encoding my coordinates as a polyline, but the polyline keeps getting URL encoded before it gets send to the server so it's not sending the correct polyline definition.

Is there a way to keep my url from being URL encoded

```
http://localhost:5000/trip/v1/driving/polyline(_p~iF~ps%7CU_ulLnnqCwugHqniHzxtZorpA~l~D%7DclLdvxAcqjOeftBgawM%7DujM%7DkrKs%7BrFbidPsrtD%7Dx~TzzqNa%7CwF??l_uW}flAqcjEmnuPo`lGungJcriNa|wF{HadC}HuaBqEewBt\k}AyRslCcVslCfLabDpEwaB).json?steps=true&overview=simplified
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow....

Comment: can you not decode it server side?

Comment: NM.  I got it.  Just used my :waypoints ref in the $resource to keep it from getting encoded.  Thx for the suggestion.